# Flask проект в нескольких файлах

Tags: python, flask

Добрый день.

Допустим, есть большой проект на flask. В одном файле неудобно редактировать. Как разнести проект по нескольким файлам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для больших приложений в Flask применяются Blueprints. Это такой аналог приложений Django. Структура проекта при этом может быть любая, рекомендую ознакомится с структурой, которую предлагают для больших проектов в официальной документации: [Larger Applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите, как это сделано во [flask-kit](https://github.com/semirook/flask-kit)-е или в [fbone](https://github.com/imwilsonxu/fbone).